# The items from directory are added in a random order but it is created problems in the programme

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tkinter, listbox

The items in the playlistbox are loaded in random order when a particular song is selected, the wrong song is played.

Tried loading different file codecs
Tried reversing the loading order by using code : playlist.revrse

```
#Suspected Problematic Code:


playlist = []

def bfolder():
    global filenamepath
    global directory
    global index

    folder = filedialog.askdirectory()
    os.chdir(folder)

    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        if filename.endswith(".mp3") or filename.endswith(".wav") or filename.endswith("flac") or filename.endswith(".ogg") or filename.endswith(".Mp3") or filename.endswith(".Wav") or filename.endswith(".Flac") or filename.endswith(".Ogg") or filename.endswith(".MP3") or filename.endswith(".WAV") or filename.endswith(".FLAC") or filename.endswith(".OGG"):
            pg.mixer.music.queue(filename)
            filename = os.path.basename(filename)
            index = 0
            playlist.insert(index, filename)
            playlist.reverse()
            playlistbox.insert('end', filename)
            index +=1
        updatelabel()


def updatelabel():
    global index
    global playlist
    v.set(playlist)





#This is probably not required but here is the code used for playbutton:

def play_button():
    global paused

    if paused:
        selected=playlistbox.curselection()
        selected = int(selected[0])
        play= playlist[selected]
        pg.mixer.music.unpause()
        statusbar['text']=os.path.basename(play),"Resumed"
        paused = FALSE
    else:
        try:
            stop_button()
            time.sleep(1)
            selected=playlistbox.curselection()
            selected = int(selected[0])
            play= playlist[selected]
            pg.mixer.music.load(play)
            pg.mixer.music.play()
            statusbar['text'] = "Playing " + ' : ' + 
            os.path.basename(play)
            showdetails(play)
        except:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error","File Doesn't Exist")
```

The items in the playlistbox are loaded in random order when a particular song is selected, the wrong song is played.

I want to load them in some kind of order, maybe order by name or size or something so that when the song is selected from the playlistbox, the highlighted song is played

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many facilities for listing the contents of a directory will return the results in what is known as "directory order".  This isn't necessarily random, but it can be surprising.

What you'll want to do is sort the results of `os.listdir()` before using those results.  You might find `sorted(os.listdir(path))` suits your needs, or you might want to sort by some other criterion.  If you want a more specific sorting, I recommend googling for, say, "python os.listdir sort by size", or whatever meets your particular sorting requirements.